# Is there a way to detect a computer's true external IP when they are connected to a VPN?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, networking, vpn

Using .NET, is there a way to retrieve the external IP of a PC if they are connected to a VPN and using the VPN as the internet gateway? My end goal is to detect if the client PC is truly on the network or if they are at a remote location.

**EDIT:** After reading some of these answers, I should be a little more specific. I guess what I'm looking for is a programmatic way of bypassing the VPN to check the true external IP of the laptop. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, testing for the IP will only result in finding it "bound" to the network; as they are connected via VPN (which is the point).  Without actually modifying the VPN client, I don't know if that is possible.  You **could test** to see if they are connected via a VPN connection, but looking at the IP will only see the current, networked connection.

Comment: Are you trying to detect this at the client or server?

Comment: at the client. the client sends it's relevant information to the server for processing

Comment: Why would you need the external IP to determine this? I'd just enumerate the addresses on the client's "up" network interfaces and see if one has an internal IP and external IP both  in your network's internal IP range. For example, I use a VPN on my laptop, but I can determine if I'm on my home network by checking that my WiFi adapter is connected with an internal IP address of 192.168.0.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, if you are at the client, you could run ROUTE PRINT on windows and parse the output searching for the VPN specific entries. Try running the command when connected to the VPN and when connected directly and find the differences. Besides the physical adapters you should see a VPN adapter and all external routes going through it. If you want to bypass the VPN to get the external IP, which you would probably do by accessing and external server, you would have to add a route to that server through the ethenet adapter. But I have used VPN clients that block that, meaning that all traffic must go through the VPN, so this might not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. However you can detect if the client comes from VPN by checking if IP that you got has been used a lot, or is known to host a VPN server (you can have a list).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to assign a range of IP's specific to the VPN, then just test to see if the internal IP is in that range.

Comment: One can be "on the VPN" using a local connection.  Laptops for example might always use the VPN whether they are actually "in the building" or not.  Depends on how things are setup.

Comment: It depends what the purpose of the question is. If it's for security reasons, a laptop could be in the building, but connected via VPN through a public wi-fi connection, and should be considered to be "remote".

Comment: @EricJ. Laptops being always connected to the VPN, whether in the building or not, would be extraordinarily poor practice, and that should go without saying.  The idea of assigning IP ranges specifically to VPNs is one of the better options here; without modifying the VPN client itself, and adding some sort of token to the connection.  I would assume the VPN would be using a different set of "keys" anyway, and that encrypted connection should be spot-able.

Comment: @plast1K: Sure it's poor practice.  But it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly detect the "real" IP, but you may be able to infer whether they are on the network by looking at factors specific to your network topology.

For example, ping times for computers on the local network will be drastically different than ones that are external.  That is not 100% perfect, but should give you a very solid indicator.

The route may also be different (does traceroute show different routes for devices on the local network vs. remote devices?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a server, say HTTP server, you cannot, as one of the main purposes of VPN is to provide anonymity. The machine goes on to internet via VPN, so unless client bypasses vpn and sends the real ip address to you, you can't.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is a technique to bypass the VPN and use the gateway configured for normal network usage when not connected to the VPN. Is this possible?

Comment: Unless you have physical or full remote access to the target computer, no.

Answer (score 0):

usually when you are connected to a vpn you have an ip of a subnet that not is the same of the subnet when you are phisically connected, but if this is not the case, you could try to run a tracert an get the response, if the firewall that manage the vpn is not the same of the router that provide connection to the network, you got it, only parse the response.

Other way to do this is get the name of the adapter with the ip, if is the vpn adapter you got it.